# Omniauth-facebook: retrieve user location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I have the following configuration in my config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
provider :facebook, id, secret, {scope: 'email, user_location, user_birthday', image_size: {width: 400, height: 400}}
```

But the authentication hash does NOT come with user's location information.

I followed the guides and read facebook's documentation, but can't figure out whats wrong. Are there any missing steps?

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

Adding user location to your `scope` just means your app has the rights to read the user's location.  It doesn't mean FB will send it to you.  You need to make an FB API call to find it.  Check out the Koala gem -- initialize it with the access_token you get from login and then call FB to find the location.

Comment: Tnks! I got confused since omniauth-facebook gem's README lists location inside the auth hash. I think it is outdated, no? https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Comment: As you work with the FB SDK, you'll learn they change things all the time without warning or apology.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use 'Koala' gem for Request Graph API

and Request with '/me/location'

Answer (score 0):

You must specify exactly which fields should be returned when getting the user's info.
It can be done with `info_fields` parameter

```
provider :facebook, id, secret, {
    scope: 'email, user_location, user_birthday',
    image_size: {width: 400, height: 400},
    info_fields: 'email, name, location'
}
```